# Java loop and how to fix it

Tags: java, loops

I think my loop is wrong, how can I fix it so I get all the names to be printed out?

```
// Course class
public class Course {

    // Data fields
    private String courseName;
    private String[] students = new String[100];
    private int numberOfStudents;

    // Constructs 
    public Course (String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    // Methods 
    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public void addStudent(String student) {
        students[numberOfStudents] = student;
        numberOfStudents++;
    }

    public void dropStudent(String student) {

    }

    public String[] getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public int getNumberOfStudents() {
        return numberOfStudents;
    }
}
```

Test the class

```
public class TestCourse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Course course1 = new Course("Data Structures");
        Course course2 = new Course("Database Systems");

        course1.addStudent("Ben Johnson");
        course1.addStudent("Mary March");
        course1.addStudent("Nora Bently");

        course2.addStudent("John Tailor");
        course2.addStudent("Sara Gardner");

        System.out.println("Number of students in Data Structure Course is: " + 
                              course1.getNumberOfStudents());

        String[] students = course1.getStudents();
        for (int i = 0; i < course1.getNumberOfStudents(); i++);
            System.out.print(students[i] + ", ");

            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Number of students in Database Systems is: " + 
                               course2.getNumberOfStudents());


    }       
}
```

So if you run this program there's an error with the TestCourse and I need to fix the loop but it looks right to me. Apparently it's not! Can anybody fix this?

Comment: remove the semicolon after the for loop.Your loop with semicolon means `for(){}` execute nothing in for loop iteration

Comment: If this fixed your issue, any of the answers will do below.  Can you mark one as the answer so it is closed?

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop in your test class is missing braces.

```
for (int i = 0; i < course1.getNumberOfStudents(); i++);
    System.out.print(students[i] + ", ");

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Number of students in Database Systems is: " + 
                       course2.getNumberOfStudents());
```

needs to be

```
for (int i = 0; i < course1.getNumberOfStudents(); i++) {
    System.out.print(students[i] + ", ");

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Number of students in Database Systems is: " + 
                       course2.getNumberOfStudents());
}
```

White space in java is ignored.   For more reading, read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestCourse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Course course1 = new Course("Data Structures");
        Course course2 = new Course("Database Systems");

        course1.addStudent("Ben Johnson");
        course1.addStudent("Mary March");
        course1.addStudent("Nora Bently");

        course2.addStudent("John Tailor");
        course2.addStudent("Sara Gardner");

        System.out.println("Number of students in Data Structure Course is: " + 
                              course1.getNumberOfStudents());

        String[] students = course1.getStudents();
        for (int i = 0; i < course1.getNumberOfStudents(); i++) {
            System.out.print(students[i] + ", ");

            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Number of students in Database Systems is: " + 
                               course2.getNumberOfStudents());

        }
    }       
}
```

I think now it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < course1.getNumberOfStudents(); i++);
```

just remove `;` here (if use `;` this means that the loop does nothing)

```
 for (int i = 0; i < course1.getNumberOfStudents(); i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to the following *for loop* to this (You have a typo error):

```
for (int i = 0; i < course1.getNumberOfStudents(); i++)
{
    System.out.print(students[i] + ", ");

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Number of students in Database Systems is: " + course2.getNumberOfStudents());
}
```

You had a semicolon at the end of the *for loop*, and you had to replace it with a bracket to indicate the loop block.

Answer (score -1):

Update your code - you are missing braces around the `if` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < course1.getNumberOfStudents(); i++) {
            System.out.print(students[i] + ", ");
}
```

Indentation in Java doesn't provide the looping; braces do. (you had a `;` which meant 'do nothing' for the loop body.)

Comment: as well as the 'what' of resolving a problem a 'why' is also useful